# Why beautiful soup css selector result is empty?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get 'a' tags inside div with the class 'x'. I'm trying this code:

```
u = urllib.urlopen('http://www.full-hd-wallpaper.com/all')
data = u.read()
soap = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soap.select("div.wallpaper_item a")
```

but the result is empty. I'm sure the selector is correct. I also tried this simple selector:

```
print soap.select("div")
```

but nothing returned. what's wrong with my code?

this is the input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/darkbrush/style.css?20140420:8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

SITE_URL = '';
SEO_ON = '3';
COMMENT_WAIT = 'Please wait 60 seconds between comments';
COMMENT_ERROR = 'An error occured in sending your comment';
WALLPAPER_SUBMIT_COMMENT = 'Submit comment';
ADDING_COMMENT = 'Adding comment';
COMMENT_ADDED = 'Comment added';
function WallpaperAddHit(id) {
    AjaxPost("/includes/wallpaper/ajax/wallpaper_hit.php", "wallpaper_id="+id, 
             function () {}
    )
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/wss.js"></script>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="" href="/rss.php" />
<title>All wallpapers - Full HD Wallpaper</title><meta name="description" content="All wallpapers All our wallpapers in one place!" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Full HD Wallpapers, wallpapers 2013, full hd wallpaper,wallpapers, HD Wallpapers, HD Wallpaper, desktops, downloads,Wallpaper,hd wallpaper download, hd wallpaper nature, hd wallpaper 1920x1080, HD Wallpaper 1080p, hd wallpaper for android, " /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-42003300-1', 'full-hd-wallpaper.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45774874-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Report popup and overlay !-->
<div id="ava-popup">
<div id="ava-popup-header">
<div id="ava-popup-title"></div>
<div id="popup-close-button" onclick="HidePopup('ava-popup');"></div>
</div>
<div id="ava-popup-content"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay" onclick="HidePopup('ava-popup')"></div>
<div class="header">
<div class="header_logo">
<a href="/"><img src="/templates/darkbrush/images/logo.png" alt="Full HD Wallpaper" /></a>
</div>
<div class="header_right">
<!--ads-->
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu_left">
<div class="menu_item">
<a href="/">Homepage</a></div><div class="menu_item">
<a href="/all">New wallpapers</a></div><div class="menu_item">
<a href="/all/downloads/1">Most Downloads</a></div><div class="menu_item">
<a href="/all/rating/1">Top rated</a></div><div class="menu_item"></div><div class="menu_item"><a href="/page/copyright-policy">Copyright policy</a></div><div class="menu_item"><a href="/page/contact-us">Contact Us</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="menu_right">
<form action="/index.php?task=search" method="get" onsubmit="searchSubmit('', ''); return false;">
<input name="task" type="hidden" value="search" />
<div class="search_contain">
<div class="search_contain_left">
<input name="q" type="text" size="20" id="search_textbox" value="Search..." onclick="clickclear(this, 'Search...')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Search...')" class="search_box" />
</div>
<div class="search_contain_right">
<input type="image" style="margin-top:7px;" src="/templates/darkbrush/images/search_button.png" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mc_bg">
<div class="main_container">
<div class="secondary_container">
<div class="left_sidebar">
<a href="/news">News</a>
<a href="/rss.php">Subscribe</a>
<a href="/links">Links</a><br />
<form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=FullHdWallpaper', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true"><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US" /><input type="hidden" value="FullHdWallpaper" name="uri" /><h5>Email Subscription</h5>
<input type="text" class="email_textbox" name="email" size="20" />
<input type="submit" class="email_button" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
<br />
<h2>Categories</h2>
<div class="category_menu_item">
<a href="/all">All wallpapers</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/abstract">Abstract</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/animals">Animals</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/nature">Nature</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/men">Men</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/children">Children</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/girls-and-women">Girls and Women</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/world">World</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/foods">Foods</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/cars">Cars</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/technology">Technology</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/holiday">Holiday</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/other">Other</a></div><div class="category_menu_item"><a href="/flower">Flower</a></div>
<br />
<h2>Tags</h2>
<div class="tag_cloud"><a href="/tag/adriana-lima-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Adriana lima wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/alessandra-ambrosio-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Alessandra ambrosio wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/amber-heard-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Amber heard wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/beyonce-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Beyonce wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/britney-spears-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Britney Spears wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/candice-swanepoel-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Candice swanepoel wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/cheryl-cole-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Cheryl cole wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/doutzen-kroes-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Doutzen kroes wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/elisha-cuthbert-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Elisha cuthbert wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/ewelina-olczak-wallpapers" style="font-size: 13px">Ewelina olczak wallpapers</a> <a href="/tag/inna-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Inna wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/jennifer-lawrence-wallpapers" style="font-size: 13px">Jennifer lawrence wallpapers</a> <a href="/tag/jennifer-lopez-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Jennifer lopez wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/jessica-alba-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Jessica alba wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/kate-upton-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Kate upton wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/lady-gaga-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Lady Gaga wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/lindsey-stirling-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Lindsey stirling wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/marloes-horst-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Marloes horst wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/natalia-vodianova-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Natalia vodianova wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/nicki-minaj-wallpaper-" style="font-size: 13px">Nicki minaj wallpaper </a> <a href="/tag/nicole-scherzinger-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Nicole scherzinger wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/rihanna-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Rihanna wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/robert-pattinson-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Robert pattinson wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/scarlett-johansson-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Scarlett johansson wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/taylor-swift-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Taylor swift wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/woman-with-car-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">Woman with Car wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/alexandra-stan-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">alexandra stan wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/alfa-romeo-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">alfa romeo wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/aston-martin-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">aston martin wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/audi-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">audi wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/bar-refaeli-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">bar refaeli wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/barbara-palvin-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">barbara palvin wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/benz-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">benz wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/bmw-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">bmw wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/bugatti-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">bugatti wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/emma-watson-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">emma watson wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/eva-mendes-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">eva mendes wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/ferrari-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">ferrari wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/ford-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">ford wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/irina-shayk-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">irina shayk wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/kate-beckinsale-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">kate beckinsale wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/katy-perry-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">katy perry wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/kelly-clarkson-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">kelly clarkson wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/lamborghini-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">lamborghini wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/megan-fox-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">megan fox wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/miranda-kerr-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">miranda kerr wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/motorcycle-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">motorcycle wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/porsche-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">porsche wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/rosie-huntington-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">rosie huntington wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/selena-gomez-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">selena gomez wallpaper</a> <a href="/tag/suzuki-wallpaper" style="font-size: 13px">suzuki wallpaper</a> </div><br />
<h2>New</h2>
<div class="module_wallpaper">
<a href="/nature/windmill-morning-sunrise-2">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5997&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="windmill morning sunrise" width="150" height="85" />
</a>
</div><div class="module_wallpaper">
<a href="/nature/landscapes-nature-roads">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5996&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="landscapes nature roads" width="150" height="85" />
</a>
</div><div class="module_wallpaper">
<a href="/girls-and-women/candice-swanepoel-model">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5995&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="candice swanepoel model" width="150" height="85" />
</a>
</div><br /> </div>
<div class="right_sidebar">
<h2>Your account</h2>
<form method="post" action="/login.php?done=1">
<div class="mini_login_form">
<p>Username</p>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="mini_login_textbox" /><br />
<p>Password</p>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="mini_login_textbox" /><br />
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" checked="checked" /> Keep me logged in</label></p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="mini_login_button" />
<a href="/index.php?task=lost_password">Forgotten your password?</a>
</div>
</form>
<a href="/index.php?task=register">Register new account</a>
<br />
<h2>Recently viewed</h2>
<div class="no_recents">None...</div><br />
<h2>Stats</h2>
<ul class="stats_ul">
<li><strong>317</strong> users online</li>
<li><strong>5729</strong> wallpapers</li>
<li><strong>76823</strong> members</li>
<li><strong>0</strong> news posts</li>
<li><strong>31</strong> comments</li>
<li><strong>19</strong> categories</li>
</ul><br />
<h2>Links</h2>
<ul><li><a href="http://thefashionshows.com/">Fashion Shows</a></li><li><a href="http://www.2topics.com">wallpapers gallery</a></li><li><a href="http://www.hdwallpaperz.com">Girls Wallpapers</a></li><li><a href="http://hdwallpaperstock.info/">High Definition Wallpapers</a></li></ul><div class="more_links"><a href="/links">More links</a></div>
</div>
<div class="center_column">
<div class="center_container">
<center>
<div class="gas">
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- wallpaper-text-728 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3574787538747201" data-ad-slot="8438048800"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> </div>
</center>
<div class="header_overflow"><h1><a href="">Homepage</a> &raquo; All wallpapers</h1></div>
<div class="ad_banner_misc">
</div>
<div class="category_sort_options">
                Sort options: <a class="sort_bold" href="/all">Newest</a> | <a class="sort_notbold" href="/all/oldest/1">Oldest</a> | <a class="sort_notbold" href="/all/rating/1">Top Rated</a> | <a class="sort_notbold" href="/all/downloads/1">Most Downloads</a> | <a class="sort_notbold" href="/all/nameasc/1">A-Z</a> | <a class="sort_notbold" href="/all/namedesc/1">Z-A</a> &nbsp; <select class="select" id="resolution_filter" name="resolution_filter" onchange="setResFilter();">
<option value="all">All resolutions</option><optgroup label="4:3"> <option value="1600x1200">1600x1200 </option><option value="1400x1050">1400x1050 </option><option value="1280x960">1280x960 </option><option value="1024x768">1024x768 </option><option value="800x600">800x600 </option></optgroup><optgroup label="16:9"> <option value="2560x1440">2560x1440 </option><option value="1920x1080">1920x1080 (1080p) </option><option value="1600x900">1600x900 </option><option value="1280x720">1280x720 (720p) </option></optgroup><optgroup label="16:10"> <option value="2880x1800">2880x1800 </option><option value="2560x1600">2560x1600 </option><option value="1920x1200">1920x1200 </option><option value="1680x1050">1680x1050 </option><option value="1440x900">1440x900 </option><option value="1280x800">1280x800 </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Apple"> <option value="2048x2048">Retina iPad </option><option value="1024x1024">iPad / iPad mini </option><option value="640x1136">iPhone 5 (&amp; iPod) </option><option value="640x960">iPhone 4/4S/iPod </option><option value="320x480">Older iPhone &amp; iPod </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Blackberry"> <option value="360x480">360x480 </option><option value="320x240">320x240 </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Google Android"> <option value="720x1280">720x1280 </option><option value="540x960">540x960 </option><option value="480x854">480x854 </option><option value="480x800">480x800 </option><option value="320x480">320x480 </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Netbook"> <option value="1366x768">1366x768 </option><option value="1024x600">1024x600 </option><option value="800x480">800x480 </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Other resolutions"> <option value="960x544">960x544 PS Vita </option><option value="480x272">480x272 PSP </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Windows Phone 7/8"> <option value="768x1280">768x1280 </option><option value="720x1280">720x1280 </option><option value="480x800">480x800 </option></optgroup></select> </div>
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- wallpaper-720 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3574787538747201" data-ad-slot="1054382805"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script><br /><br />
<div class="category_container">
<div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/windmill-morning-sunrise-2">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5997&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="windmill morning sunrise" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/windmill-morning-sunrise-2">
            windmill morning sunrise        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/landscapes-nature-roads">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5996&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="landscapes nature roads" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/landscapes-nature-roads">
            landscapes nature roads     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/candice-swanepoel-model">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5995&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="candice swanepoel model" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/candice-swanepoel-model">
            candice swanepoel model     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/bugatti-veyron-grand-sport-2014">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5994&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="bugatti veyron grand spor…" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/bugatti-veyron-grand-sport-2014">
            bugatti veyron grand spor…      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/beyonce-knowles-singer">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5993&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="beyonce knowles singer" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/beyonce-knowles-singer">
            beyonce knowles singer      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/vintage-girl">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5992&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="vintage girl" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/vintage-girl">
            vintage girl        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/jennifer-lopez-2014">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5991&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="jennifer lopez 2014" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/jennifer-lopez-2014">
            jennifer lopez 2014     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/bmw-m3">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5990&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="bmw m3" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/bmw-m3">
            bmw m3      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/tree-leaves-fog">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5989&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="tree leaves fog" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/tree-leaves-fog">
            tree leaves fog     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/hand-lips-girl">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5988&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="hand lips girl" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/hand-lips-girl">
            hand lips girl      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/spring-sheet">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5987&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="spring sheet" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/spring-sheet">
            spring sheet        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/srt-viper-2014">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5986&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="srt viper 2014" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/srt-viper-2014">
            srt viper 2014      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/animals/yellow-butterfly-red">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5985&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="yellow butterfly red" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/animals/yellow-butterfly-red">
            yellow butterfly red        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/art-girl-butterflies">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5984&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="art girl butterflies" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/art-girl-butterflies">
            art girl butterflies        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cities/eiffel-tower-2">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5983&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="eiffel tower" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cities/eiffel-tower-2">
            eiffel tower        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/hair-face-wind">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5982&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="hair face wind" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/hair-face-wind">
            hair face wind      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/bmw-f30">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5981&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="bmw f30" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/bmw-f30">
            bmw f30     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/purple-ears-field">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5980&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="purple ears field" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/purple-ears-field">
            purple ears field       </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/other/bike">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5979&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="bike" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/other/bike">
            bike        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/porsche-carrera">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5978&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="porsche carrera" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/porsche-carrera">
            porsche carrera     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/mountain-nature-landscape">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5977&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="mountain nature landscape" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/mountain-nature-landscape">
            mountain nature landscape       </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/cars/suzuki-gsx-r600-motorcycle">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5976&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="suzuki gsx r600 motorcycl…" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/cars/suzuki-gsx-r600-motorcycle">
            suzuki gsx r600 motorcycl…      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/road-mountain">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5975&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="road mountain" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/road-mountain">
            road mountain       </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/car-2">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5973&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="car" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/car-2">
            car     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/brunette-dress">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5972&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="brunette dress" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/brunette-dress">
            brunette dress      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/girls-and-women/model-dress">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5971&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="model dress" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/girls-and-women/model-dress">
            model dress     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/animals/africa-elephants">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5970&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="africa elephants" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/animals/africa-elephants">
            africa elephants        </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/green-trees-forest-akes">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5969&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="Green trees forest akes" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/green-trees-forest-akes">
            Green trees forest akes     </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/animals/wild-cheetah-alone">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5968&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="wild cheetah alone" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/animals/wild-cheetah-alone">
            wild cheetah alone      </a>
</div>
</div><div class="wallpaper_item">
<a href="/nature/lake-3">
<img src="/image.php?width=229&amp;height=129&amp;id=5967&amp;nocache=1&amp;dothumb=1" alt="lake" />
</a>
<div class="wallpaper_item_name">
<a href="/nature/lake-3">
            lake        </a>
</div>
</div> </div>
<br />
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- wallpaper-720 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3574787538747201" data-ad-slot="1054382805"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script><br />
<div class="category_pages">
<div class="pagination_wrap">
<b><a href="#"><font color="#2B6FE4">1</font></a></b> <a href="/all/newest/2">2</a> <a href="/all/newest/3">3</a> <a href="/all/newest/4">4</a> <a href="/all/newest/5">5</a> <a href="/all/newest/6">6</a> <a href="/all/newest/7">7</a> <a href="/all/newest/8">8</a>  ... <a href="/all/newest/188">188</a> <a href="/all/newest/189">189</a> <a href="/all/newest/2">Next &raquo;</a> </div>
</div>
<br />
<div style="padding: 10px">
<center>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ad_banner_footer"><br style="clear:both" />
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- wallpaper-text-728 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3574787538747201" data-ad-slot="8438048800"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.wallpapersitescript.com">Wallpaper Site Script</a> - Copyright <a href="http://www.avscripts.net">AV Scripts</a> 2014 <a href="http://www.avscripts.net"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We cannot know what is going on without the input. Could you post your HTML code here (or elsewhere and link to it)?

Comment: I just tried and it worked for me. You could try reading the HTML from a file to see if the problem is the URL you're using.

Comment: @bgschiller Code is not working for me even from a file! can you try my Url? Question updated with actual Url.

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi It works for me using the real URL. Could something be wrong with your installation of BeautifulSoup? Did you install with `pip install beautifulsoup4`? I'm not sure what could be the problem. If you're running a script from a file, try using the interactive prompt.